# How to map pixels as snow/ non-snow to create Landsat binary maps

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to create and export binary snow cover maps.

Is the code ( var thres = ndsi.lte(0.4).rename('snow','non-snow');) correct for thresholding snow and non-snow pixels?

When I want to export my maps I get an error:

> ID: IVRHW63534LSEG6CMQNSG3V4
>
> Phase: Failed
>
> Runtime: 2s (started 2022-06-30 12:21:50 +0200)
>
> Attempted 1 time
>
> Error: Image.rename: The number of names (2) must match the number of bands (1). (Error code: 3)

```js
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-113.7614013671875, 40.54917381877071],
      [-113.7614013671875, 40.461463065241],
      [-113.6295654296875, 40.461463065241],
      [-113.6295654296875, 40.54917381877071]]], null, false);

 var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA");

 var image = l8.filterBounds(roi)
              .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than', 3)
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2015,2016,'year'))
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(11,4,'month'));

 var img = image.mean().select(['B3', 'B6']);

 var ndsi = img.normalizedDifference(['B6', 'B3'])
 .rename('NDSI')
 .clip(roi);

 var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                 "bands":["NDSI"],
                 "min":-0.1789,
                 "max":0.3323,
                 "palette":["fcff25","ffb354","1714ff"]};

 Map.addLayer(ndsi, imageVisParam, 'NDSI');
 Map.centerObject(roi);

//Thresholding

//If NDVI less or equal to 0.4 => 1 (snow) else 0 (non-snow)

 var thres = ndsi.lte(0.4).rename('snow','non-snow');

 Export.image.toDrive({
 image: thres.float(),
 description: 'NDSI',
 scale: 30,
 region: roi,
 folder: 'GEE',
 });
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Providing a bullet list of questions is a reliable way to generate closure votes. Please [Edit] the Question to focus on your most pressing problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct. You need to change, for example, to:

```
var thres = ndsi.lte(0.4).rename('ndsi');
```

After that, I could export **thres** image to my Drive folder without any problem. However, it is a completely black image in QGIS because all NDSI values are lesser than 0.4 in that image (all pixels equal to one). So, all pixels are showing snow presence according that criterion.

Comment: I changed the code var thres = ndsi.gte(0.4).rename('ndsi'); to get the pixels => 0.4 but still the image is completely black and I only get one image, however in the GEE visualization it shows several images based on differetn paths and rows. Do you think it is because of this code
 var img = image.mean().select(['B3', 'B6']); selects mean values? I need single NDSI images for the chosen period. But it should give me all images as you explained in my last question "I produced the mean (img) for that collection (it could be used as a function for each image in Image Collection". Thanks a lot.